# How to transform from tibble to dataframe as it is?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, wrangle

First, I averaged the player's data and scaled it down.

```
player <- player %>%
   group_by(NM) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

And this is the result.

```
head(player) 
# A tibble: 6 x 26
  NM       NO   MIN `2PTM` `2PTA` `2PT(%)` `3PTM` `3PTA` `3PT(%)`   FGM   FGA `FG(%)`    FTM   FTA `FT(%)`    OR    DR   REB
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a.~     6  918.  0.32   0.72     14.8   0.44   1.9       13.7 0.76  2.62     17.9 0.18   0.32     6.5  0.38  0.64  1.02 
2 b.~    13 1681.  3.41   6.43     54.5   0.574  2.13      19.7 3.98  8.56     47.4 0.907  1.33    35.5  2.04  3.22  5.26 
3 c.~    31  704.  0.921  2.16     36.0   0.421  1.18      21.1 1.34  3.34     38.6 0.447  0.658   19.7  0.526 1.16  1.68 
4 d.~    21  968.  0.885  1.88     32.6   0.846  2.08      22.1 1.73  3.96     35.3 1.15   1.35    39.1  0.462 1.04  1.5  
5 e.~     9  105.  0.118  0.294     8.82  0.176  0.412     11.8 0.294 0.706    18.6 0.0588 0.118    2.94 0.294 0.176 0.471
6 f.~     2  509.  0.571  1.57     21.4   0.286  1.29      10   0.857 2.86     17   0.286  0.714   21.4  0.143 0.714 0.857
# ... with 8 more variables: AST <dbl>, TO <dbl>, STL <dbl>, BS <dbl>, PF <dbl>, FO <dbl>, PP <dbl>, PTS <dbl>
```

Then, I used mutate function. But it didn't added column. I heard tibble was limited. Because of that, I transformed it into a data frame.

```
> head(as.data.frame(player))
  NM NO       MIN      2PTM      2PTA    2PT(%)      3PTM      3PTA   3PT(%)       FGM       FGA    FG(%)        FTM
1 a  6  918.0600 0.3200000 0.7200000 14.800000 0.4400000 1.9000000 13.74000 0.7600000 2.6200000 17.94000 0.18000000
2 b 13 1680.8889 3.4074074 6.4259259 54.462963 0.5740741 2.1296296 19.72222 3.9814815 8.5555556 47.42593 0.90740741
3 c 31  704.0526 0.9210526 2.1578947 35.973684 0.4210526 1.1842105 21.05263 1.3421053 3.3421053 38.63158 0.44736842
4 d 21  967.5000 0.8846154 1.8846154 32.576923 0.8461538 2.0769231 22.11538 1.7307692 3.9615385 35.26923 1.15384615
5 e  9  105.1765 0.1176471 0.2941176  8.823529 0.1764706 0.4117647 11.76471 0.2941176 0.7058824 18.64706 0.05882353
6 f  2  508.5714 0.5714286 1.5714286 21.428571 0.2857143 1.2857143 10.00000 0.8571429 2.8571429 17.00000 0.28571429
     FTA     FT(%)        OR        DR       REB       AST        TO        STL         BS        PF         FO        PP
1 0.3200000  6.500000 0.3800000 0.6400000 1.0200000 0.8000000 0.2200000 0.44000000 0.00000000 1.9400000 0.64000000 0.6400000
2 1.3333333 35.481481 2.0370370 3.2222222 5.2592593 1.2592593 0.8333333 0.74074074 0.42592593 3.3888889 1.70370370 4.5925926
3 0.6578947 19.736842 0.5263158 1.1578947 1.6842105 0.4736842 0.1842105 0.28947368 0.02631579 1.3684211 0.65789474 1.6842105
4 1.3461538 39.115385 0.4615385 1.0384615 1.5000000 0.9230769 0.8846154 0.50000000 0.03846154 2.1923077 2.46153846 1.6153846
5 0.1176471  2.941176 0.2941176 0.1764706 0.4705882 0.0000000 0.1176471 0.05882353 0.00000000 0.1176471 0.05882353 0.1176471
6 0.7142857 21.428571 0.1428571 0.7142857 0.8571429 0.7142857 0.5714286 0.28571429 0.00000000 1.4285714 0.57142857 0.8571429
    PTS
1 2.1400000
2 9.4444444
3 3.5526316
4 5.4615385
5 0.8235294
6 2.2857143
```

Q.
1. Why i can't use mutate function? Actually, because of no error code, it works. But no column is added.

2. How to transform tibble to data.frme intactly? I guess it's from dealing with irrational number.

Comment: Please post some reproducible data.

Comment: Where is your `mutate` line? Please show code. Are you assigning back to data frame?

Comment: mutate line : player <- mutate(player, TS <- PTS/(2*FGA +0.44*FTA)

Comment: Use `=` inside mutate, not `<-`. `player <- mutate(player, TS = PTS/(2*FGA +0.44*FTA)` should work. (This is true of all R functions, not just mutate.)

Comment: And what do you think is wrong with your data frame transformation? Looks like it worked just fine to me

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted a dataframe  right out of that transformation you could try:

```
already_a_DF <- player %>%
       group_by(NM) %>%
       summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% as.data.frame
```

Comment: The %>% as.data.frame was helpful ... I did not realise you could to that